# How to get more than one field with django filter icontains

Tags: python, django, search

I am trying to compare my query search to all my model fields, but I can't figure how to do it in more than one field.

this is my code.

```
expense = Expense.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).order_by('date')

q = request.GET['q']
result = expense.filter(name__icontains=q)
```

I want to check in: `name`, `amount`, `category`

Thanks in advance

Comment: If amount is an integer, you will probably won't want to use icontains, but a regular lookup.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From Django documentation:

"Keyword argument queries – in filter(), etc. – are “AND”ed together. If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with OR statements), you can use Q objects."

```
from django.db.models import Q
expense.objects.filter(
    Q(name__icontains=q) | Q(amount__icontains=q) | Q(category__icontains=q)
)
```

I'm not sure about the type of amount and category in your model so icontains may not work on them.

see [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: You should use filter instead of get, because get return only one object.

Comment: You're right about category, maybe because its a foreign key?

Comment: if it is a foreign key you could access the name field with double underlines: category__name__icontains for example.